# How to set up a specific video card to be used by default in Windows?

Tags: windows, video, graphics-card, performance, fan

I have two video cards in this laptop:

```
Name: "Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630"
DedicatedVideoMemory: 128.00 MB
SharedSystemMemory: 24500.85 MB

Name: "NVIDIA Quadro RTX 5000 with Max-Q Design"
DedicatedVideoMemory: 16170.00 MB
SharedSystemMemory: 24500.85 MB
```

When I check the task manager, the first one "Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630" gets used by default and is usually maxed out (not on this screenshot though):

[image]

*I made a screenshot above when there's nothing running on that laptop, or in other words, it had a Windows Explorer open and a Firefox browser with this page.*

As a result the laptop's fans seem to go crazy even after a short duration of activity. (I am also checking CPU utilization and that one stays relatively low: less than 5% on average.)

So I'm wondering if I can somehow set up the other, a beefier video card, to be used by default?

PS. I can find multiple articles online that show how to do it per app. But I don't want it per app. I need it to be used for everything by default.

Comment: Please update your question to include the laptop make and model.

Comment: As above. Your laptop may or may not (most likely) allow setting the dGPU only. The usual scenario is it toggling to the dGPU when and ONLY when needed and that is defined by a standard set of rules. Those rules can be changed *per app* and that's it, end of story. Before asking you should do your own research / read the user's manual, or simply opening UEFI settings and checking there for yourself.